# Nothing to be done for makefile

Tags: makefile

I am new to make files and after looking at some examples, couldn't understand why my makefile is not running. I am trying to create a c++ object file that depends on `main.cpp`, `A.cpp` and `B.cpp`. This object file will take a text file as input and show its text and run code in it.

```
spl : 
    g++ -o spl main.cpp A.cpp B.cpp
cat-error1 : spl
    cat error1.txt
run-error1 : spl
    spl error1.txt
```

I thought it may be tab problem but here is the output from `cat -e -t -v makefile` :

```
spl : $
^Ig++ -o spl main.cpp A.cpp B.cpp$
cat-error1 : spl$
^Icat error1.txt$
run-error1 : spl$
^Ispl error1.txt
```

I am getting this error:

> Nothing to be done for makefile.

I am running the makefile in Mac OSX terminal using:

```
$ make makefile
```

where *makefile* is the name of my makefile.

Comment: How do you run the makefile? You didn't show us.

Comment: I edited the question and added. basically using 'make makefile' in OSX terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `make makefile` is wrong. Where did you read to do that?

`make` always reads from the file named "Makefile"; the argument you should give it is the name of the target to build, but your makefile has no target called "makefile"! Furthermore, it's not clear what you expected that to do, as you have three targets.

You meant to write `make spl`, or `make cat-error1`, or `make run-error1`.

Comment: ... or `make -f makefile` if someone doesn't trust makefile is the default makefile...